# Bash script not found El Capitan

Tags: terminal, bash, macos, command-line

I have created a Bash script that simply does `ls -l`.

In Mavericks and older versions of OSX I simply made a symlink to the script and put it in the `/usr/bin` folder (`ln -s ll.sh /usr/bin/ll`) and I could then execute the script using `ll` from any folder.

Since upgrading to El Capitan I am unable to load this script. I have disabled SIP so that I am able to create the symlink and the script is definitely executable. The location (`/usr/bin`) is definitely in the $PATH and I have even tried adding a path to the script into the $PATH too.

Nothing seems to work, all I am getting is `-bash: ll: command not found`.

I have restarted the terminal after each update to the $PATH and I have tried `source ~/.bash_profile` but neither are making any difference.

**Edit:** I also tried adding the current directory of the scripts to the $PATH and that was also giving the same error. In the end I have aliased all my scripts so that they will run.

Comment: when you run your ll.sh does it work ?

Comment: If all the the `ll.sh` -script_ is doing is `ls -l` then you should use an _alias_ instead. Set `alias ll='ls -l'` in the `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`, whichever you're using. See [6.6 Aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases) in the [BASH Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: I used the `ls -l` as an example, I have quite a few scripts that do different things. I could make an alias for them all but I wondered if the previous implementation was still possible. If I run the .sh script it runs fine.

Comment: A couple of things...  There really is no need to use an extension on the _shell scripts_, e.g. `ll.sh` simply needs to be `ll`.  I have a separate directory I put all of my scripts in and add that directory pathname to the `$PATH`.  I have  150 scripts I've written in that directory and not one has an extension yet they're all executable.  Some even have _symlinks_ (not Finder Alaises, and not to be confused with _bash aliases_) to shorter names to type in the Terminal for convenience.  This way all of my scripts are more centrally located and do not get mixed in with system executables.

Comment: Can you please please add the full script to the question? And the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/ll `?

Comment: Convention would warrant that the system's path- `getconf PATH` is only modified by the vendor regardless of SIP. Nor would one add scripts that alter the shell's environment to your PATH. System wide "scripts" (no shebang and sourced from a shell rc file) belong in /etc and user "scripts" belong in their home folder.

Comment: My hypothesis still is that there is something wrong with the script itself. But as long as you don't include it in your question text we won`t be able to verify that. Anyway, using aliases (or shell functions) is the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your setup, but a different (perhaps better) way to do this same thing is via Bash's `alias` command. At the command prompt, type in:

```
alias ll="ls -l"
```

Then you can just type `ll` and get a full listing. If you wish to make this permanent, you can put it in the `.bashrc` file in your home directory, which you can create if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can alias the command to a file location `ll=~/scripts/ll.sh`, which is what I have ended up doing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Just read the comments and see that you're looking for a general solution, rather than that specific example. I'll leave my previous answer in case it helps someone, but here's a more general solution.

My first piece of advice: leave `/usr/bin` alone. There's no reason to mess with it and there are many reasons *not* to mess with it. Instead, add a directory somewhere else, put you scripts there, and add it to you `$PATH` variable. If you want this just for your user, you could create a `scripts` or `bin` directory in your home directory, or if you want it globally available you could put it under `/usr/local`, e.g. `/usr/local/scripts` or `/usr/local/bin`. Then, in the `.bashrc` file in your home directory, add the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts:/usr/local/scripts
```

If you would rather have your commands override a system command (should they have the same name) then you could do the following, instead:

```
export PATH=~/scripts:/usr/local/scripts:$PATH
```

If you want this set for all users, then there is a global `/etc/bashrc` file that you can add the above to.

In order to edit the global `bashrc` or modify `/usr/local` you need root/admin privileges.

Comment: Note that /usr/local/bin is already in the default PATH, so if you put things there you don't have to worry about customizing the PATH.

Comment: Don't you need quotes around PATH absolute path?